# Why do my doors behave unexpectedly in ROBLOX Studio using TweenService()?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm building a Maze Runner game for ROBLOX and I've gotten to scripting the doors, so I utilized ROBLOX's built in "TweenService()" to do it. In theory, the doors should slide into the walls like in the Maze Runner. But This keeps happening and i don't know why! They rotate into the gap rather than sliding. I would show an image but i can't. | = walls V = doors.
What should happen |><| what happened |^^|

My Code:

```
        TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
    Door = script.Parent.Door2
    Door1 = Door:WaitForChild("Door1")
    Door2 = Door:WaitForChild("Door2")
    local TweenInformationIn = TweenInfo.new(

        6,
        Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,
        Enum.EasingDirection.In,
        0,
        false,
        0
    )

    local Door1Close = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -769.185)}
    local Door2Close = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -814.271)}
    local Door1Open = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -749.831)}
    local Door2Open = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -834.331)}
    local Tween1Open = TweenService:Create(Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Open)
    local Tween2Open =  TweenService:Create(Door2, TweenInformationIn,Door2Open)
    local TweenClose =  TweenService:Create(Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Close)
    local Tween2Close =  TweenService:Create(Door2,TweenInformationIn,Door2Close)

    Tween1Open:Play()
    Tween2Open:Play()
```

Comment: have you tried differend EasingDirections and Styles? Just a guess

Comment: CFrames contain both position and rotation information. Your target position only defines the position. It could be that the starting position of your doors have some rotation that the tween is trying to deal with when it tweens to the "open position"

Comment: @Piglet Yeah I did. Nothing is working.

Comment: @Kylaaa how can I tell the script the postition i want?

Answer (score 0):

Your tween code looks fine.

It could just be that the CFrames you have defined are missing rotation information. 
In your example, the tweens you have made are trying to move door 1 to `Position (1226.993, 131.187, -769.185)` and `Orientation (0, 0, 0)`.

You need to check the Orientation property of your doors and make sure that Orientation is preserved in your final CFrames. You can apply that rotation to the position by multiplying it by another CFrame.

Two quick examples of this are :

```
-- create a door that swings close
local Door1OpenPos  = CFrame.new(0, 5, 10) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(0, 90, 0)
local Door1ClosePos = CFrame.new(0, 5, 15) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(0,  0, 0)

-- create a door that slides close
local Door2OpenPos  = CFrame.new(20, 5, 0) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(0, 90, 0)
local Door2ClosePos = CFrame.new(30, 5, 0) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(0, 90, 0)
```

Your sliding doors need to make sure that the Orientation is the same at the start and end of your tween.

Hope this helps.